# how to generate code for exception java dynamically ( at build time)

Tags: java, jackson

Many times, i usually see exception class is always same in my project. like below

```
public class CustomException extends BaseException  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomException() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public CustomException(String message, Throwable t) {
        super(message, t);
    }
}
```

can we able to generate the code at build time using jackson or annotation processor? advise me here to proceed,if possible.

i can see jackson generating POJO classes. so i am asking, will it be good way to do as well?

Comment: Do you really mean _at build time_?

Comment: yes. it would be good at build time. or suggest me if any better way

Comment: So, you want to write `throw new CustomException("my message", e);`, hit save in the editor, and the IDE generates the code? If so, you could write your own IDE plugin to do it. Here is an intro to writing [Eclipse plugins](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html).

Comment: No... My Question is generate CustomException,CustomException1,CustomException2....etc  class files only.. like that, we may have to create mutliple exception to handle the our scenarios.

Comment: Ok, let's suppose you generate those exceptions. What is their purpose then, how are they used, when are they thrown/caught?

Comment: hmm.. we will throw/catch the exception ( as a developer will write specific scenarios to throw or catch exceptions) and handle accordingly.  But, my problem statement to configure all the exception at one place. So, Business analyst can add Exception list in any json/xml for us with proper descriptions.....